# Getting information from different tables in an database

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
       User
---------------------
id        primary key 
name      varchar 
mobile    varchar
```

**Sample data**:   `(1, airtel, '9887456321,6985326598,88523695874')`

```
         Client
---------------------------
id              primary key
clientname      varchar 
mobileno        varchar
```

**Sample Data**: `(1,John Doe, 9887456321)`

I want to search the client name from first table on the basis of mobile field value.

If mobile field has values`(9887456321,6985326598,88523695874)` then how do I know which client name that particular mobile phone number belongs to?

Comment: Can a single mobile value contain three different numbers separated comma's or is it that there are three rows with the three numbers mentioned?

Comment: Thanks George. Things look a lot clearer after the edit. @Neo Some restructuring definitely looks in order. What is the relationship between users, clients, and mobiles? Does a client only have 1 mobile? If so is it meant to always have one and only one corresponding record in the users table?

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a matching column between your `client` table and the other table. It is not clear from your description what that column is. From what you have said, I believe your schema looks like:

```
Create Table MobileNumbers
(
    Id ... not null Primary Key
    , Name varchar(??) not null
    , Mobile varchar(??) not null
)

Create Table Client
(
    Id ... not null Primary Key
    , ClientName varchar(??) not null
    , MobileNo varchar(??) not null
)
```

Assuming that Client.Mobile matches MobileNumbers.Name, we have:

```
Select ...
From Client
    Join MobileNumbers
        On MobileNumbers.MobileNo = Client.Mobile
Where Client.Mobile In('9887456321','6985326598','88523695874')
```

In this structure, I'm assuming that each Mobile value contains a single number and not a comma-delimited list of numbers. If it is actually the case that the a single cell can contain multiple values (please edit your original post is that is the case), then as Martin Smith mentioned, you need to normalize the data.

**EDIT**

Given your revision of the OP, the root problem is that you have multiple values in a single column. The right solution would be to normalize the mobile numbers into a second table:

```
Create Table UserMobileNumber
(
    UserId ... not null References User ( Id )
    , Carrier varchar(??) not null
    , Mobile varchar(??) not null
    , Constraint UC_UserMobileNumber Unique ( Mobile )
)
```

Then the solution becomes trivial:

```
Select ...
From User
    Join UserMobileNumber
        On UserMobileNumber.UserId = User.Id
Where UserMobileNumber.Mobile In('9887456321','6985326598','88523695874')
```

However, in the interim, what you need is a split function:

```
Create Function dbo.udf_Split
(   
    @DelimitedList nvarchar(max)
    , @Delimiter nvarchar(2) = ','
)
Returns Table
As
Return
    (
    With CorrectedList As
        (
        Select Case When Left(@DelimitedList, Len(@Delimiter)) <> @Delimiter Then @Delimiter Else '' End
            + @DelimitedList
            + Case When Right(@DelimitedList, Len(@Delimiter)) <> @Delimiter Then @Delimiter Else '' End
            As List
            , Len(@Delimiter) As DelimiterLen
        )
        , Numbers As 
        (
        Select TOP (Len(@DelimitedList) + 2) Row_Number() Over ( Order By c1.object_id ) As Value
        From sys.columns As c1
            Cross Join sys.columns As c2
        )
    Select CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen As Position
        , Substring (
                    CL.List
                    , CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen     
                    , CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value + 1)                           
                        - ( CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen ) 
                    ) As Value
    From CorrectedList As CL
        Cross Join Numbers As N
    Where N.Value < Len(CL.List)
        And Substring(CL.List, N.Value, CL.DelimiterLen) = @Delimiter
    )
```

Now you can do something like:

```
Select ...
From User
    Outer Apply dbo.Split( User.Mobile ) As M
    Join Client
        On Client.MobileNo = M.Value
Where M.Value In('9887456321','6985326598','88523695874')
```